# What is the meaning of hising？

Tags: word-meaning

> Under the upswelling tide he saw the writhing weeds lift languidly and sway reluctant arms,**hising** up their petticoats, in whispering water swaying and upturning coy silver fronds. Day by day: night by night: lifted, flooded and let fall.

Which is from Joyce's book,Ulysses.
Does it mean holding up？

Comment: Could it be a misspelling of "**hiking** up their petticoats", which would simply mean "raising"?

Comment: It has been mentioned before. Ulysses is one of the hardest books to read.  I don't go so far as Fumblefingers; if you want to read it you are allowed to!  But I think there needs to be realistic expectations. You will not understand it.  Every line has multiple meanings,  this one, for example is from a Irish drinking song about a woman who "pisses like a man", the thought provoked by the fact that Stephen has just pissed into a tide pool, which is why suddenly you get all these alterations and silibance.

Comment: So please explain: **Why are you reading chapter 3 of Ulysses**  Have you already read chapters 1 and 2?  Do you have a set of notes and annotations to work with? What is you aim in reading Ulysses?

Comment: @JamesK I have read chapter 1,2,3 and Hamlet by Shakespeare, I can do it.I am a little boring of the story style, so i want to try some different literature.i get three versions of translation in Chinese , and a annotation book by Gifford in   PDF version , but i prefer the website of Joyceproject. I want to learn more words, but in the mean time appreciating literature works . to just remember words in a dictionary is boring. I'm patient , and ready to read it over by about 240 days. chapter 1,2,3 seem to be harder to read than the other chapters, so I'm confident about the rest

Comment: I've never seen the word. **Hoisting** or **hitching** could be other possibilities.

Comment: @JamesK sometimes my VPN is not OK, so i ask the questions about chapter 3,2,1 now as it is OK now. damn     the gov who bans even an English learning website, that's why they lose eventually.

Comment: Is the meaning, at least the "outer" meaning of , not clear from the Chinese translation?  Indeed, how do the various translators express this line? Do they do better than Google:  她掀起她的衬裙

Comment: 哈哈，haha, Google is rightthe 3 versions of the translation are clear too, that's lifting.but I'm curious at the word as it is not explained in anywhere, neither Internet nor books. it haunts me. maybe i should not cost so much time on it, but just understand them by the context,which , I heard of, is an important methods to pass TOEFL,etc.

Comment: You probably need to read each chapter four times.  First in Chinese, then read the English without any notes and without a dictionary.  Read quickly see if there is anything you understand.  Then read slowly with detailed annotations, a dictionary and making references to the Chinese. Use a study guide to each chapter which explains the context of each line and makes the connections to the vast array of high brow and low brow culture that Joyce references.  Finally, having gained the encyclopedic knowledge you need to understand the text, read it again slowly but without notes.

Comment: It's not explained because it is a "nonce" word.  That it has only one recorded use in English: in Ulysses.  The drinking song is not part of the written culture.#

Comment: @JamesK my reading pattern is almost like yours, especially chapter 3,2,1, about 6 or 7 times——Chinese, Chinese VS English, Chinese VS English,English without explanations,in the first reading I checked all the information I need.

Comment: @JamesK  mistake...not the first reading,but in the second round of reading them paragraph by paragraph, I checked all the information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a line from an Irish drinking song.  You've already seen it in Chapter 1

> Old Mary Ann,
> She doesn't give a damn!
> But hising up her petticote,
> ...

The song is unfinished in the book, but we can suppose that the last line is "she pisses like a man!"

So "hising" is a dialect or variant pronunciation of "hoising" (an obsolete word that is now only found in the fixed expression "hoist by his own petard") or possibly "hitching", either way the meaning is *lifting*, and it is used in this form to make the assonance with "pisses"

The outer meaning should be clear from your Chinese translation.

Don't expect Joyce to be confined to such things boring as a dictionary.  Still less to the grammar taught at school.  In this chapter you are inside a  complex, highly educated, extremely intelligent mind. Stephen is trying to compose a poem in his head "rhythm begins..." but there are distractions. There are lots of half thoughts, ideas that go nowhere. And this is Proteus, nothing is fixed everything changes shape.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that hising "is a dialect or variant pronunciation of 'hitching'"? Based on the consonants, I'd think it would be more likely to be a dialectal or variant pronunciation of ["hoising"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoising).

Comment: Possibly. I don't know if there is evidence either way.

Answer (score 1):

It  means "lifting", but I don't see it in the online dictionary, so I'm unsure whether it's in my latent vocabulary, or just a word whose meaning I  understand from the context. Petticoats are an old-fashioned female undergarment. You could imagine a woman lifting them to prevent their getting wet. This idea is supported by the coy up-turning of fronds, as if the reeds were exhibitionists.

Comment: thank you, I suppose it means that by the context,but i want native speakers to confirm and rest my mind.

Comment: There are no native speakers of Joycian English.  The last native speaker died on 13 Jan 1941.